# ICU can't built statically with MRI even it's compiled with `-fPIC`

Tags: c++, ruby

I've been working on the ICU binding for MRI Ruby. The configuration runs smoothly in OS X. But it fails miserably on Travis (Ubuntu 12.04 with gcc 4.8+).

The build file downloads, extracts, compile ICU into a static library and link with my glue code to a shared object. It's supposed to be smooth but the link error pops up everytime.

`` linking shared-object icu/icu.so
relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata._ZL11_uErrorName' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC` was found ``

Rubygem build configuration file:
https://github.com/fantasticfears/icu4r/blob/master/ext/icu/extconf.rb#L88-L89

I've tried with `--enable-static --disable-shared --disable-renaming` but it doesn't work.
It works if I build it with `--enable-static --disable-renaming` but gem fails when the actual user is loading it. It even fails in my machine for rubygems. Though I can build it by `rake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked on the icu-support mailing list and got an reply from Rob Boehne.

> In a dynamic language like Ruby or Python, you will need a dynamic library or framework to use ICU.  That is why —disable-shared doesn’t work.
>   The problem is that one object file needs –fPIC instead of –fpic which is the default.  So the fix is to configure with —enable-shared and add –fPIC to CFLAGS.

This explains the story. And this passes the CI and can be distributed by the package manager rubygems.
I tried to build shared but it fails my build locally (OS X). It might be the LD_PATH problem in OS X in particular.

The change is nasty but you might want to have a look. https://github.com/fantasticfears/icu4r/commit/44403ba5d1579fbc45e6a15912a6d61e8f4eace6